# ASP.NET CORE Angular 6 add third party component

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm workin on ASP.NET Core and Angular 6 template, I decided to add a third party component ([This component)](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/).

I added it into package.json file as ng-pick-datetime (and It's installed on node modules) and then, I added it into webpack.config.vendor.js in nonTreeShakeableModules section with the same name as package.json but when I run the webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js command I got a few errors for module not found.

What's the correct way to add the third party component into webpack?.

Thanks.

error list

```
 ERROR in ./~/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/date-time.module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/a11y' in 'C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OptimNg-Core\trunk\OptimNg.Core\node_modules\ng-pick-datetime\date-time'
 @ ./~/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/date-time.module.js 3:0-47
 @ ./~/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/index.js
 @ ./~/ng-pick-datetime/picker.js
 @ dll vendor

 ERROR in ./~/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/date-time-picker.component.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/overlay' in 'C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OptimNg-Core\trunk\OptimNg.Core\node_modules\ng-pick-datetime\date-time'
 @ ./~/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/date-time-picker.component.js 14:0-62
 @ ./~/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/index.js
 @ ./~/ng-pick-datetime/picker.js
 @ dll vendor
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

first of that's pure client side which mean that's it's pure Angular and have nothing to do with ASP.NET.

the problem is that you didn't add your package module into the app.module file, so angular didn't loaded it.

from your third party component link:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS} from 'ng-pick-datetime';

// learn more about this from
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat
export const MY_NATIVE_FORMATS = {
    fullPickerInput: {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'},
    datePickerInput: {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'},
    timePickerInput: {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'},
    monthYearLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
    dateA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'},
    monthYearA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long'},
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_NATIVE_FORMATS},
    ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

make sure that your imports includes: OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule

and that they are imported.

Comment: I forgot that step, I already added and and got the same error.